# gradle-play-publisher publishing first version

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-play-publisher

Im trying to push apk using [gradle-play-publisher](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher) but getting following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:publishApkRelease'.
> No application was found for the package name com.xxx.xxx. Is this the first release for this app? The first version has to be uploaded via the web interface


* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:publishApkRelease'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
...
```

How can I push my first apk using `gradle-play-publisher` even without using web interface for the first time? any pointer?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to upload the first version manually.

Please see my issue on this here: https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/issues/75#event-353579248.

Comment: So there's no way to make first upload automatic? is this restriction by google itself? Then whats the purpose after all? Im building web interface for public users to create and upload apk directly from our own web interface, How can I achieve it?

Comment: Why? That is what the Google Play console is for. You have to upload the first version.

Comment: suppose there are multiple users using our custom web interface for apks creation for different apps, and for user convenience we wants to make google app submission process fully automatic to make it steady process. so users can quickly create apps dynamically and submit them without manual upload, what are your recommendations in this case?

Comment: You have to upload the first version manually, then you can use this plugin. That is all.

Comment: is this restriction enforced by Google play service itself or by this plugin?